# Find the minimum and maximum value of $ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa$ given that $a+b+c+d+e+f=12$.

Tags: inequality, polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima

Let $a,b,c,d,e,f$ be non negative real numbers. Find the minimum and maximum value of $ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa$ given that $a+b+c+d+e+f=12$.

The minimum value will come as $0$ since we can take $a=b=c=d=e=0$ and $f=12$.

But how to find the maximum value? I tried to rearrange the terms but I couldn't be successful. I feel that the maximum value is $36$ since we can put $a=b=6$ and set the rest of the terms as $0$ and then the maximum value becomes $36$.

But these are just experimental verifications but can someone provide a strong, rigorous proof for both minimum and maximum value? Why can't we apply $AM-GM$ to get the minimum value?

Comment: what Kind of numbers are $a,b,c,d,e,f$?

Answer (score 3):

For $a=b=c=d=e=0$ and $f=12$ we get a value $0$, which is a minimal value.

Since $(a+b+c+d+e+f)^2\geq4(ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa)$, which is
$$(a-b+c-d+e-f)^2+A\geq0,$$
where $A\geq0$, we get a maximal value: $36$.

Comment: Could you justify the last inequality? The asker may not understand immediately why.

Comment: @Parcly Taxel I fixed my post. See now, please.