# Find the maximum value of $ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa,$ given that $a+b+c+d+e+f=1$

Tags: inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

After looking at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1416397/if-a-b-c-d-e-f-are-non-negative-real-numbers-such-that-abcdef-1-then-f), I framed the following question.

> If $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c+d+e+f=1$, then find the minimum and maximum value of $ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa$

**My Attempt:**

$\frac{a+b+c+d+e+f}6\ge(abcdef)^{\frac16}\implies\frac1{36}\ge(abcdef)^{\frac13}$

Also, $\frac{ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa}6\ge(abcdef)^{\frac13}$

Dividing the second inequality by first, I get,

$ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa\ge\frac16$

I got the minimum value. For maximum value, I think [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2295950/find-the-minimum-and-maximum-value-of-abbccddeeffa-given-that-abcde) has a solution, but not able to understand how it framed the inequalities.

Also, the minimum value could have been achieved by assigning each variable as $\frac16$. In such equality cases, how do we know whether we'll get minimum value or maximum value, without solving algebraically?

Comment: your minimum is wrong. You are claiming that $A\geq B$ and $C\geq B$ implies $C\geq\max B.$ Or just set $a\to 1$ and $b,c,d,e,f\to 0$ and you will see that the minimum can be arbirtrarily small positive number.

Comment: @dezdichado thanks

Comment: I guess you can simply apply the approaches used in the linked posts to your problem.
 
Note that:
$$ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa \\ =b(c+a)+d(c+e)+f(e+a)\\ \leq (b+d+f)(a+c+e)\\ \leq \frac {((b+d+f)+(a+c+e))^2}{4}=\frac{1}{4}.$$ 

Clearly, $\frac{1}{4}$ is attainable at $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$ and $c=d=e=f=0.$

Comment: @RezaRajaei in the linked posts, the variables are non-negative, so, zero is allowed. I am taking variables as positives.

Comment: @RezaRajaei but yes, if we take variables to tend to zero then $\frac14$ seems like a good maximum value, thanks.

Comment: @aarbee I see. The answer does not change. However, this time, $\frac{1}{4}$ is not attainable.

Comment: Yes, supremum, not maximum

Comment: @aarbee You're welcome.

Comment: @aarbee
You wrote _“I think this post has a solution, but not able to understand how it framed the inequalities.”_
Indeed the answer is somehow curt.
Expressed slightly differently, the key inequality is:
$$\begin{array}{lr}
&(a+b+c+d+e+f)^2-4(ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa)\\[3pt]
&=(a-b+c-d+e-f)^2+4(ad+be+cf)\geqslant0.
\end{array}$$
In our situation it implies that $1-4(ab+bc+cd+de+ef+fa)\geqslant0$.

Comment: @jpboucheron, got it, thanks